# $(Ax)(t)= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-\frac{t}{s}}}{\sqrt{s}} x(s) ds$ for $A : C[0,1] \to C[0,1] $ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

The question is as follows:

Show that the linear operator $(Ax)(t)= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-\frac{t}{s}}}{\sqrt{s}} x(s) ds$ for $A : C[0,1] \to C[0,1] $ is compact.

$\textbf{About the question:}$

This question is the same as [linked-to result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560271/axt-int-01-frac-sints-mid-t-s-mid-frac13-xs-ds-for).

I actualy do not know how to deal with such kind of questions!

Can you please let me now that how can I think about it? What are the conditions for them to be compact?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, since $C[0,1]$ is infinite-dimensional, we need a norm to begin the study. Here I use $\|.\|_{\infty}$.

A linear operator is compact iff the image of the closed unit ball is relatively compact. We note $B$ the closed unit ball of $C[0,1]$. $B=\{f\in C[0,1],\ \|f\|_{\infty}\le1\}$.

From [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_d%27Ascoli), $A(B)$ is relatively compact iff $A(B)$ is equicontinuous in $[0,1]$ and $\{f(t),\ f\in A(B)\}$ is relatively compact. Since $\{f(t),\ f\in A(B)\}\subseteq\Bbb R$, the set is relatively compact iff it's bounded.

- Prove that $\{f(t),\ f\in A(B)\}$ is bounded:

Let $f \in B$, thus $\|f\|_{\infty}\le1$, and we have that
\begin{align}
\forall t\in[0,1],\ |A(f)(t)|&=|\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-t/s}}{\sqrt{s}} f(s) ds|\\
&\le\int_{0}^{1} |\frac{e^{-t/s}}{\sqrt{s}} f(s)| ds\\
&\le\int_{0}^{1} \frac{|f(s)|}{\sqrt{s}} ds\\
&\le\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\ ds\cdot\|f\|_{\infty}\\
&\le2
\end{align}

- Prove that $A(B)$ is equicontinuous:

Let $t \in [0,1]$, $\epsilon>0$. Since $g:\ (t,s)\mapsto\frac{e^{-t/s}}{\sqrt{s}}$ is a continuous function in $[0,1]^2$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\forall t'\in[t-\delta,t+\delta],\ \forall s\in[0,1],\ |g(t',s)-g(t,s)|\le\epsilon$.

Let $f \in B$, for all $t'\in[t-\delta,t+\delta]$, we have that
\begin{align}
|A(f)(t')-A(f)(t)|&=|\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-t'/s}-e^{-t/s}}{\sqrt{s}} f(s) ds|\\
&\le\int_{0}^{1} |g(t',s)-g(t,s)|\cdot|f(s)| ds\\
&\le\epsilon\cdot\|f\|_{\infty}\\
&\le\epsilon
\end{align}

Comment: Many thanks! Very clever answer!